# Uncheck checkbox toggle when Reactable table is refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Reactable table which has a column of checkboxes, where in the column header has a checkbox that acts as a toggle for checking and unchecked the column.

The problem I am seeing is when the table is refreshed the toggle is still checked, which is affecting the state on those table rows, plus some rows are still checked because of the toggle.

I have tried adding an onload method to the reactable table and passed in event to get to the toggle but I unable to get the target.checked.

Can someone please explain how I can uncheck all checkboxes including the checkbox in the table header when the table is refreshed?

```
_onload = (e) => {
    if(e.target.checked) {
           e.target.checked = false ;
    }
}
```

The method above is called inside the table tag using:

```
onload={this._onload(e)}
```

Comment: Please post whatever you have done so far..

Comment: I guess you are going wrong way. You should maintain state to do this.

Comment: Please explain and you provide me with an example of what you mean

Comment: <input
       type='checkbox'
       checked={this.state.checkAll}
       onChange={this.selectAll.bind(this)}
       name='select_all'
       value='all'
      />

Comment: I already have a onchange event on the checkbox but this does work on the table refresh. This the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110308/discussion-between-ved-and-andy5).

Comment: Sorry, missed your reply as I was having dinner. There are two types of checkboxes. One in the header with a onclick method, and each row has a onchange method. Now, the problem I have is if the checkbox in the header is still checked and the table is refreshed, it mess up the state. What I want to is on the load of table to uncheck the checkbox in the header if it checked, which in turn I hope will keep the state correct